# Android - Run TimerTasks in Sequence

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, timer, kotlin-coroutines

I want to run multiple timers in sequence. When one timer completes the next should start. I thought of using the Handler class however this has the effect of running the timers in parallel. As can be seen by the output below.

Is there a way to make the Timer operation block the thread until its complete or is there a better way to achieve this? Maybe with Futures or Kotlin Coroutines?

I'm new to Android. On iOS I have been able to do this with OperationQueue/Operation(set isAsynchronous = true).

```kotlin
class SequentialTimerTasks {
    private val handlerThread: HandlerThread = HandlerThread("HandlerThread")
    private lateinit var threadHandler: Handler

    class TimerCountTask(private val id: Int) : TimerTask() {
        private val TAG = "TimerCountTask"
        var count = 0
        override fun run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Runnable $id RUNNING TIMER $count")
            count++

            if (count >=10) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Runnable $id CANCEL TIMER $count")
                this.cancel()
            }
        }
    }

    class RunnableTask(private val id: Int) : Runnable {
        private val TAG = "RunnableTask"
        override fun run() {
            Log.d(TAG, "Runnable $id run() called")
            val timer = Timer()
            timer.schedule(TimerCountTask(id), 0, 1000)
        }
    }

    fun start() {
        handlerThread.start()
        threadHandler = Handler(handlerThread.looper)
        threadHandler.post(RunnableTask(1))
        threadHandler.post(RunnableTask(2))

    }
}
```

OUTPUT

```
Runnable 1 run() called
Runnable 2 run() called
Runnable 1 RUNNING TIMER 0
Runnable 2 RUNNING TIMER 0
Runnable 2 RUNNING TIMER 1
Runnable 1 RUNNING TIMER 1
Runnable 2 RUNNING TIMER 2
Runnable 1 RUNNING TIMER 2
Runnable 2 RUNNING TIMER 3
Runnable 1 RUNNING TIMER 3
Runnable 2 RUNNING TIMER 4
Runnable 1 RUNNING TIMER 4
Runnable 2 RUNNING TIMER 5
Runnable 1 RUNNING TIMER 5
Runnable 2 RUNNING TIMER 6
Runnable 1 RUNNING TIMER 6
Runnable 2 RUNNING TIMER 7
Runnable 1 RUNNING TIMER 7
```

Comment: I think You need create "queue Event"  executes the specified Runnable on the worker thread.

Comment: Do you want a Handler based solution only or are you okay with using Kotlin coroutines?

Comment: @ArpitShukla coroutines would be a great option. I've been reading about them but unsure how to implement multiple timers/repeated tasks in sequence

Comment: Are you using android ViewModels in your code?

Comment: No I'm just running this as a simple object with no lifecycle or other platform dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Your usage of `HandlerThread` is superfluous — this class does not do anything useful in your code, and it's Thread is no better than any random Thread you started yourself or the threads created by other libraries. Sure, it has a Looper/Handler, but you are not doing anything useful with Handler to justify it's presence.

`Timer` is ancient legacy from Java versions prior to Java 5. It's existence predates Android and nobody should use it these days. Citing from Timer's documentation:

> Java 5.0 introduced the java.util.concurrent package and one of the concurrency utilities therein is the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate or delay. It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the Timer

The biggest mistake in your code is using 2 separate thread pools: a single-threaded `HandlerThread` "pool" and a hidden thread pool internally used by `Timer`. In general you should always minimize usage of multi-threading in your code and isolate "normal" code from multi-threaded artifacts. Using multiple types of threads (other than Android main thread) goes contrary to that purpose.

In theory it is possible to fix your original code to work as intended, but because of the reasons above I suggest to abandon both `HandlerThread` and `Timer` and switch to single thread pool, based on ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor:

```java
final int PERIOD = 1000;
final int SECOND_TASK_DEADLINE = 10000;

final ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

final Runnable firstTask = new Runnable() {
  int count = 0;

  public void run() {
    count++;
    Log.d(TAG, "Runnable 1 RUNNING, timer " + count);
  }
};

final Runnable secondTask = new Runnable() {
  int count = 0;

  public void run() {
    count++;
    Log.d(TAG, "Runnable 2 RUNNING, timer " + count);
  }
};

final Future<?> firstFuture = executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(firstTask, 0, PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

executorService.schedule(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
    firstFuture.cancel(false);

    executorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(secondTask, 0, PERIOD, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
  }
}, SECOND_TASK_DEADLINE, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Unlike your original code, the code above runs your business logic exclusively on 1 thread — the thread of ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.

This allows you to take advantage of *natural mutual exclusion*: despite performing no explicit thread synchronization, your code never races or runs concurrently with itself... because there is only 1 thread.